# Vb.net using List (Of String) over time in a for next routine slows down

Tags: vb.net, performance, list

EDIT: I have put the full 2 subs and 1 function that are being used.
I have also placed comments around the section that is slowing down over time.

Before anyone mentions FileHelpers, I do not want to use a 3rd party component.

So, I have a CSV file, 3.5million rows and I am parsing each line of the CSV and inserting it into SQLite (non-index table) to keep the speed up. I am also buffering 100,000 lines at a time from the CSV - all is well with the world, but in my loop (after I have buffered 100,000 lines into a List of string, the following code goes through and split up each line accordingly builds up an insert string and off it goes - approx 1000 rows are processed a second - I can live with that but after a couple of hundred thousand rows, it starts to slow down to around 200 rows per second. Eventually, after about 600,000 rows, it crawls down to 25 rows and further on, (not sure at what point) after 2 million + rows slows down to 10-15 rows. I'd really like to keep the 1000 rows a second (or even improve on it if possible.

I have left out some code, a fixsquote routine that gets called to sort out any quotes as well as an IF THEN statement to determine if there are quotes and to split it up differently - for this particular 3.5 million row csv, there arent any quotes so I just wanted to reduce the amount of code I am posting here to make it clearer to read.

Originally, I used the ancient array to manage the split and that was the same, a slow down after X thousand rows, but looking on the internet, it seemed that a list of string would be better so I converted a few lines of code to utilise the list of string in my loop and it hasnt made a difference. I have a feeling although I dont seem to be using arrays, Im baffled by the eventual slow down. Something either isnt being reused properly and maybe stack or heap issue that I am not aware of?

I do not get a slow down during the bulk INSERT - I can remove the insert altogether and execution to SQLITE, so SQLITE isn't the issue. Its something to do with the List or String. I am going to try the suggestion of upping the .net version- I did have this on 4.6 so will up it to 4.7.1 ******

Here is the code, maybe someone can spot something obvious.

```
  Private Sub CSVImport

    Dim SQLStr As New Text.StringBuilder
    Dim BigSQLStr As New Text.StringBuilder
    Dim Comma As String = ""
    Dim FirstInsertStr As New Text.StringBuilder
    Dim BufferT As Integer = 0

    Try


        If IO.File.Exists(FileName) = True Then


            Dim C As Integer
            Dim line As String



            FirstInsertStr.Clear()
            FirstInsertStr.Capacity = 0
            FirstInsertStr.Append("INSERT INTO " & Chr(34) & DestinationTableName & Chr(34))
            FirstInsertStr.Append(" (" & Chr(34) & "LON" & Chr(34))
            FirstInsertStr.Append(", " & Chr(34) & "LAT" & Chr(34))
            FirstInsertStr.Append(", " & Chr(34) & "NUMBER" & Chr(34))
            FirstInsertStr.Append(", " & Chr(34) & "STREET" & Chr(34))
            FirstInsertStr.Append(", " & Chr(34) & "UNIT" & Chr(34))
            FirstInsertStr.Append(", " & Chr(34) & "CITY" & Chr(34))
            FirstInsertStr.Append(", " & Chr(34) & "DISTRICT" & Chr(34))
            FirstInsertStr.Append(", " & Chr(34) & "REGION" & Chr(34))
            FirstInsertStr.Append(", " & Chr(34) & "POSTCODE" & Chr(34))
            FirstInsertStr.Append(", " & Chr(34) & "ADDRESSIO_ID" & Chr(34))
            FirstInsertStr.Append(", " & Chr(34) & "HASH" & Chr(34))
            FirstInsertStr.Append(") VALUES (")



            BufferT = 0

            BigSQLStr.Clear()
            BigSQLStr.Capacity = 0

            ' Create new StreamReader instance with Using block.
            Using reader As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(FileName)
                ' Read one line from file
                line = reader.ReadLine ' first line in headers so ignore

                Do Until line = Nothing

                    ' Stop
                    Dim BufferRead As New List(Of String)
                    Dim BufferLoad As Integer = 0

                    Do Until BufferLoad = 100000
                        line = reader.ReadLine
                        If line = Nothing Then
                            Exit Do
                        End If

                        BufferRead.Add(line)
                        BufferLoad += 1
                    Loop

                    Dim Z As Integer = 0

                    For Z = 0 To BufferLoad - 1

                        BufferT += 1

                        Comma = ""
     ' ************** I BELIEVE THE SLOWDOWN IS WITHIN HERE, FAST AT FIRST, THEN SLOWS DOWN AFTER 30k RECORDS OR SO **********                           
                        Dim objFields2 As New List(Of String)

                        If BufferRead(Z).Contains(Chr(34)) = True Then
                            BufferRead(Z) = FixsQuote(BufferRead(Z))

                            objFields2.AddRange(Split(BufferRead(Z), ",", Chr(34), True))
                        Else
                            objFields2.AddRange(BufferRead(Z).Split(","))

                        End If


                        With SQLStr
                            .Clear()
                            .Capacity = 0
                            For C = 0 To objFields2.Count - 1
                                If C > 11 Then
                                    Exit For ' we only ever want the first 11 fields.
                                End If
                                If C > 0 Then
                                    Comma = ","
                                End If
                                If IsDBNull(objFields2(C)) = False Then
                                    If objFields2(C).Contains(Chr(34)) = True Then
                                        If objFields2(C).Replace(Chr(34), "").Length > 0 Then
                                            .Append(Comma & "'" & FixsQuote(objFields2(C).Replace(Chr(34), "")) & "'")
                                        Else
                                            .Append(Comma & "Null")
                                        End If
                                    Else
                                        If objFields2(C).Length > 0 Then
                                            .Append(Comma & "'" & FixsQuote(objFields2(C)) & "'")
                                        Else
                                            .Append(Comma & "Null")
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                Else
                                    .Append(Comma & "Null")
                                End If
                            Next

                            BigSQLStr.Append(FirstInsertStr.ToString)
                            BigSQLStr.Append(.ToString)
                            BigSQLStr.Append(");")

                            ' Now Insert what we have
                            If BufferT = 1000 Then

                                Using OleCMD As New SQLite.SQLiteCommand(BigSQLStr.ToString, AddressesIOSQLDB)
                                    OleCMD.CommandTimeout = 0
                                    OleCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
                                End Using

                                BigSQLStr.Clear()
                                BigSQLStr.Capacity = 0
                                BufferT = 0
                            End If


                        End With


                        objFields2.Clear()
                        objFields2 = Nothing
                    Next

                    BufferRead.Clear()

    ' ****************** end of what i believe is the slow down ****************

                Loop
                If BufferT > 0 Then
                    Try
                        Using OleCMD As New SQLite.SQLiteCommand(BigSQLStr.ToString, AddressesIOSQLDB)
                            OleCMD.CommandTimeout = 0
                            OleCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        End Using
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Stop
                    End Try
                    BufferT = 0
                End If
            End Using
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        Stop
    End Try


    BigSQLStr.Clear()
    BigSQLStr.Capacity = 0

    FirstInsertStr.Clear()
    FirstInsertStr.Capacity = 0

    SQLStr.Clear()
    SQLStr.Capacity = 0

   End Sub



Private Function FixsQuote(ByVal s As String) As String
    Return s.Replace("'", "''")
End Function



Private Function Split(
    ByVal expression As String,
    ByVal delimiter As String,
    ByVal qualifier As String,
    ByVal ignoreCase As Boolean) As List(Of String)
    Dim _Statement As String = String.Format("{0}(?=(?:[^{1}]*{1}[^{1}]*{1})*(?![^{1}]*{1}))", Regex.Escape(delimiter), Regex.Escape(qualifier))

    Dim _Options As RegexOptions = RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.Multiline
    If ignoreCase Then _Options = _Options Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase

        Dim _Expression As Regex = New Regex(_Statement, _Options)
        Return _Expression.Split(expression).ToList
End Function
```

Comment: Check your posted code. There is an End If, a Loop and an End Using instructions that don't match

Comment: A little thing you could try is not to reset the Capacity of your stringbuilder every time. Resetting to zero means that the class reallocates memory every time it need to grow its internal buffer. Better start with a large enough capacity and keep it fixed. Of course you reset the length to zero at each loop (Clear or Length = 0 are the same thing)

Comment: What is `SQLStr`, `BigSQLStr`? There's some mysterious `Loop` before `If BufferT > 0`. If you want to parse CSV file, I would recommend [TexFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser) class, which, I hope, could speed up your code. :)

Comment: And does SQLite support batch processing?

Comment: This code is very rough on the GC heap.  But explaining such a slowdown is only possible if you have 4.6 on the machine, the bug was fixed in 4.6.1.  Make sure by using Perfmon.exe, look at the .NET CLR Memory > % Time in GC counter.  But it is surely SQLite grinding on these giant SQL commands with an ever growing dbase.  Make sure by using Stopwatch to observe the amount of time spent in the ExecuteNonQuery() method.  Google "sqlite bulk insert" to get ahead.  And watch out for the disk drive, if you have an SSD now then your user might be slowed down a great deal more with a spindle drive.

Comment: Hans, just updated it to 4.7.1, going to run it now on a 3million row csv - cheers - will let you know how it goes when it gets to the 100,000 record mark

Comment: Will take a look at the TextFieldParser class JohnyL, it did cross my mind, so will do a bit of research on that

Comment: Upgrading to 4.7.1 hasnt had any noticeable effect Hans, Im going to have a go at Steve's suggestion of not resetting the capacity on the strings, see if that has any effect otherwise I will go check out JohnyL's suggestion. Thank you all - most appreciated for your time looking at this with me :) At least I have 2 options I can try.

Comment: Instead of building `BigSQLStr`, you may be better served by using a Transaction and sending multiple simple Insert commands.  See [Make your SQLite bulk inserts very fast in C# .NET](https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/make-your-sqlite-bulk-inserts-very-fast-in-c/) for an example.

Comment: Ok - its definitely something to do with BigSQLStr text stringbuilder - it seems to be that, that is causing it to slow down over time. Execution of SQLite is fine, that takes a second or so to do the 1000 inserts, so TnTinMn might be onto something here, maybe if I perform a Begin/End Transaction and commit, not using the BigSQLStr text stringbuilder will increase the speed (it looks like exponentially in my tests so far) though I'd be disappointed if it was that , as the stringbuilder class has been amazing up until now

Answer (score 0):

I cant believe this but after looking at TnTinMn's suggestion (which made the transation take less than a second for the actual transations as well as removing the BigSQLStr and SQLStr text stringbuilders (because I am now executing each insert within a transaction, im pumping in 20,000 records a second. Blown away lads, blown away. Thank you all so much for making me disect my code and not thinking that the string builder is the solution for everything. From now, Im putting my large inserts into transactions and leaving the text string builder when I can, this is so much quicker now I cant believe it (and I have verified it with record counts in the database).